# Selecting from two tables

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following query in android

> query = "SELECT docid as _id," +
>                       KEY_ID + "," +
>                       KEY_NAME + "," +
>                       " from " + filter +
>                       " where " + KEY_SEARCH + " MATCH '" + txt + "';";

it selects from the the table depend on the filter

what I wanna do is to have a filter "all" to select from two tables with one query

how I can do it ? 
thanks

Comment: the two tables have nothing in common, can i use it ?

Comment: I don't think you can use

Answer (score 1):

Please look into using PreparedStatements (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Inlining variables is a good way to allow SQL injections.

To answer your question, use an inner join (implicit or explicit).

Answer (score 0):

simple way:

```
String sql = "SELECT ColumnName, ColumnAge FROM table1 SomeColumn= " + SomeValue + " UNION 
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnAge FROM table2 SomeColumn = " + SomeValue; 
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two tables together and they have the same table structure, you can union the two with

SELECT * FROM filter1
UNION
SELECT * FROM filter2

If the two tables don't have the same schema *and* aren't linked in a key relationship then it doesn't make any sense to try to do this.

If they don't have the exact same schema but there are columns they have in common then you can replace the `SELECT *` with `SELECT [col1],[col2]` in both.